# Express router adding middleware in an array

Tags: express, middleware

I'm following a tutorial and we have an auth middleware, as well as express-validator middleware. The code below works, but I'm having trouble finding documentation as to why I need to add an array to include the auth and other middleware? If I would have tried this on my own, I assumed it would look more like:

```
router.post('/', middleware, middleware, middleware, (req, res) => {}
```

I'm still new to this, so I apologize if it's a silly question.

```
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('status', 'Status is required').notEmpty(),
      check('skills', 'Skills is required').notEmpty()
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
  // More code here
)
```